# c++14 return a value by reference to optimize performance

Tags: c++, performance, c++14, copy-elision, return-value-optimization

I have a method that ultimately will take a value from an internal api call

```
auto val = api->post(req);  //step 1

// the post returns a class of "type json"

json api::post(const request& request) { //step 2

   // do some job
   json j = << some json data>>
   return j;

}
```

Now there is a third step that prepares the http response back to the external caller.

```
response server::http_response(const json &final_jsond) {

    auto response = response{final_json}; //that makes the json a string for the http payload
    response.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return response;
}
```

Now, this code works, however I am wondering if I am missing some modern C++ principles in order to avoid copying the json object from one call to another

Can the above code be optimized by using modern c++ methods to become faster?

returning by reference maybe?

Comment: The three main compilers are all good at RVO (Return Value Optimization) like for example copy-elision. And you could possible use "move" constructors and `std::move` to avoid copying as well.

Comment: wy don't you return by reference?

Comment: @nivpeled a reference to what, to a local variable? That would be a bad idea.

Comment: @nivpeled because that would generate a problem.

Comment: Btw, returning by reference was there since a long time ago before the **modern** C++ comes. It has nothing to do with the modern stuff.

Comment: Everything looks normal taking into account RVO. You can consider to pass arguments by rvalue ref (e.g. maybe response has mv-ctor?). But from your code I don't think it will give you anything. By const reference looks good for this example.

Comment: unless sizeof(...) is big then just ensure that you have a move constructor and return by value. You don't need std::move here

Comment: I am passing by value and constructor of response std::move(final.to_string))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, the return should be OK as written. If it's reasonable for `server::http_response` to consume its argument and if `response` actually holds onto a `json` or onto data in it, then you could do

```
response server::http_response(json&& final_json) {
    auto response = response{std::move(final_json)}; //that makes the json a string for the http payload
    response.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return response; // You don't need std::move here.
}
```

I use this pattern sometimes when copying is expensive. It forces the caller to do `myResponse = myServer.http_response(std::move(final_json));`, which is desirable for performance. If the caller wants to keep their `json` object, then they can instead call `myServer.http_response(json(final_json));`. Put another way, if `http_response` takes an rvalue reference, then the caller can provide it either by `std::move`ing or by constructing an unnamed temporary. But then the inefficiency of copying is on the caller.

PS

Have you measured this to be a performance bottleneck?

PPS

Having `response` be a type name and a variable name is a questionable choice.